# How to add empty rows in output csv?

Tags: powershell, csv, server, diskspace

I am using the following script to generate a report for disk space utilization, But the output csv file does not have any spaces/blank rows between different servers, So how do I add the spaces/blank rows to increase readability ??

```
$LogDate = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
$File = Get-Content -Path C:\StorageReport\Servers.txt

$DiskReport = ForEach ($Servernames in ($File)) 

{Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk <#-Credential $RunAccount#> `
-ComputerName $Servernames -Filter "Drivetype=3" `
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
} 

$DiskReport | 

Select-Object @{Label = "Server Name";Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
@{Label = "Drive Letter";Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
@{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size / 1gb)}},
@{Label = "Free Space (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) }},
@{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = {"{0:P0}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size)}} |

Export-Csv -path "C:\StorageReport\DiskReport_$logDate.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn; 

$messageParameters = @{                        
                Subject = "Weekly Server Storage Report"                        
                Body = "Attached is Weekly Server Storage Report.All reports are located in C:\StorageReport\, but the                

          most recent  is sent weekly"                   
                From = "Email name1 <Email.name1@domainname.com>"                        
                To = "Email name1 <Email.name1@domainname.com>"
                CC = "Email name2 <Email.name2@domainname.com>"
                Attachments = (Get-ChildItem C:\StorageReport\*.* | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1)                   
                SmtpServer = "SMTPServerName.com"                        
            }   
Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: You mean a ro with just commas? If you want a completely blank line, why even use csv?

Comment: @DougMaurer yes I wont mind a row with just commas....csv for using it in excel....would a txt file open in excel similar to a csv file...I mean in separate cells ??

Comment: As aside, why the need for `(Get-ChildItem C:\StorageReport\*.* | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1)` when you already have the full path for the csv file you have created earlier `"C:\StorageReport\DiskReport_$logDate.csv"` ?

Comment: @Theo because the $logdate will be different for each file and I cannot explicitly provide it...running this in task scheduler I would need to change the script every time I would need to run this.

Comment: Why don't you add the blank lines to the report when you go to read it?  That way you don't modify the original data.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Theo yes it worked !! Apparently the problem was my input servers.txt file....in the first row I had "Servers" and the following rows had the server names...so I just removed the first line and it worked ! Thanks Theo.

Comment: @Theo Hey Theo...cuz of Doug Maurer comment...i was wondering is there any better export option than csv ?

Comment: There are always other ways of exporting this kind of info. It all depends on the purpose of the excercise. If you only need to send it out in an email, you could think about formatting it in a nicely styled HTML table. A CSV file however has the great advantage that you can open in Excel and do stuff with the data like creating graphs. Also, a csv file is very easy to import and manipulate in PowerShell if you need to do something with the data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my version of Excel (2016) accepts (and shows) blank lines in the input csv, I can not guarantee this will also be the case in other versions, so I think it is best to include a line with just commas in the csv, effectively adding a row with all fields empty.

To do that, you could output the Csv file **inside** the loop where you iterate over the different servers with `-Append` switch added.

```
$LogDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmm'
$File    = Get-Content -Path C:\StorageReport\Servers.txt
$OutFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\StorageReport' -ChildPath "DiskReport_$LogDate.csv"

# because we now are Appending to the csv, we must make sure we start off with a new file
if (Test-Path -Path $OutFile -PathType Leaf) { 
    Remove-Item -Path $OutFile -Force
}

foreach ($Server in $File) {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server -Credential $RunAccount -Filter "Drivetype=3" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object @{Label = 'Server Name';Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
        @{Label = 'Drive Letter';Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
        @{Label = 'Total Capacity (GB)';Expression = {'{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Size / 1gb)}},
        @{Label = 'Free Space (GB)';Expression = {'{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) }},
        @{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = {'{0:P0}' -f ($_.freespace/$_.size)}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation -Append

    # add a line with just commas (empty fields) below this server info to the file
    Add-Content -Path $OutFile -Value (',' * 4)
}
```

Next, go ahead and send the email. My remark on that would be to simply do

```
Attachments = $OutFile
```

---

**EDIT**

Looking at the error you show in your comments, I suspect the input file where you read the server names either starts with a blank line, or has whitespace surrounding the server name, which causes the `Get-WmiObject` command to fail.

When this returns `$null`, there wil be no properties to write to the CSV file and because of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` there is nothing to stop the script writing zilch to the file anyway.

Below code does extensive error-checking on this, both in reading the file and stripping empty lines and whitespaces, testing beforehand if the server is on-line or not and it now uses a `try{..} catch{..}` block.

```
$LogDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmm'
# make sure you skip empty or whitespaace only lines and trime the values
$File    = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\StorageReport\Servers.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }).Trim()
$OutFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\StorageReport' -ChildPath "DiskReport_$LogDate.csv"

# because we now are Appending to the csv, we must make sure we start off with a new file
if (Test-Path -Path $OutFile -PathType Leaf) { 
    Remove-Item -Path $OutFile -Force
}

foreach ($Server in $File) {
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Could not connect to server '$Server'"
    }
    else {
        try {
            Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server -Credential $RunAccount -Filter "Drivetype=3" -ErrorAction Stop |
            Select-Object @{Label = 'Server Name';Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
                @{Label = 'Drive Letter';Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
                @{Label = 'Total Capacity (GB)';Expression = {'{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Size / 1gb)}},
                @{Label = 'Free Space (GB)';Expression = {'{0:N1}' -f ( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) }},
                @{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = {'{0:P0}' -f ($_.freespace/$_.size)}} |
            Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation -Append

            # add a line with just commas (empty fields) below this server info to the file
            Add-Content -Path $OutFile -Value (',' * 4)
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Error getting drive information for server '$Server'`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it is best to include a line with just commas in the csv, effectively adding a row with all fields empty" - yes this is what I wanted....Thanks so much...I have not tried this yet....I will get back to you soon.

Comment: do you think "mm" should be removed from date format because if the minute changes, join-path may get any problem ?

Comment: @DavidKent Join-Path won't have any trouble with it. How often does this scheduled task need to run? I would keep the minutes, otherwise chances are you are overwriting files that were created within the same hour. This should be no problem, but I don't know how many files you want to keep.

Comment: this is supposed to run once every three days

Comment: @DavidKent Then there is no problem at all. Since `Join-Path` is used very early in the script to define the csv file you are creating and we consistantly keep using that variable `$OutFile` it doesn't matter if the minute, hour, day or even the year changes. That's the file we create and therefore that's the file we send in the email as attachment.

Comment: @DavidKent That is why I commented to do `Attachments = $OutFile` so you know for sure you will send the correct file. If you do `Attachments = (Get-ChildItem C:\StorageReport\*.* | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1)` at the very last moment, you **may** run into trouble if by the time you get there in the code some newer file has been created in that folder.

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\scripts\ServerStorageReport\DiskReport_202009281206.csv. The 
appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: . To continue with mismatched properties, add 
the -Force parameter,

Comment: and then retry the command.
At line:17 char:5
+     Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: DiskReport_202009281206.csv had 7 rows of commas only...no server details.

Comment: @DavidKent It works when I test it.. Are you sure the `Get-WmiObject` actually succeeds?

Comment: yes it does ...because if I remove Append then the csv contains info about the last server...cuz rest gets overwritten.

Comment: Bro how do I solve this ? Seems like -Append is causing some issue...maybe cause it cant Append to a blank file ? What's your PS ver ? BTW I tried using -Force aslo...but then I got error about  something ..."name"...

Comment: @DavidKent Take off `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` . I suspect the first server (or blank line in the input file) is causing this.

Comment: Actually the issue was in the csv file....i think i had removed the first line from the csv which contained the word servers.....has been working ever since.